# Read/write Postgres large objects with DBI & RPostgres

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql

I'm trying to use the large object (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/largeobjects.html) feature of PostgreSQL in R, and I have some trouble writing and reading using `{DBI}`/`{RPostgres}`.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```sh
# Getting the db
docker run --rm --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d -p 5433:5432 postgres
```

```r
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(
  RPostgres::Postgres(),
  dbname = "postgres",
  host = "localhost",
  port = 5433,
  user = "postgres",
  password = "mysecretpassword"
)
```

Creation works :

```r
> dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT lo_create(1234);")
  lo_create
1      1234
```

But then I have a hard time figuring out how to write an R object to this large object.
For example, how would I write `mtcars` as a large object in Postgres using `{DBI}` and `{RPostgres}`?

And then, how do I read it back again in R?

Answer (score 2):

Consider R's `serialize()` (the underlying build of .RData/.RDS formats) to save R objects into a Postgres `OID` column for large objects and use Postgres v10+ [server-side large object functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/lo-funcs.html) to create and retrieve content. Below can possibly work with `bytea` types by removing all `lo_*` functions.

Assuming table structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table(
   ...
   r_object OID
   ...
)
```

To append the R object:

```r
# PREPARED STATEMENT
sql <- "INSERT INTO my_table(r_object) VALUES (lo_from_bytea(0, ?r_obj))"

# BIND PARAMETER OF SERIALIZED RAW VECTOR
query <- DBI::sqlInterpolate(conn, sql, r_obj = serialize(mtcars))

# EXECUTE ACTION
dbExecute(conn, query)
```

To retrieve the R object:

```r
sql <- "SELECT lo_get(r_object) AS r_data FROM my_table"
pg_data <- dbGetQuery(conn, sql)

# UNSERIALIZE RETURNED RAW VECTOR
mtcars_from_pg <- unserialize(pg_data$r_data[1])
```

---

Alternatively, you can use Postgres' [**`TEXT`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype-character.html) type with unlimited length and R's `dput` (ASCII representation of R objects) with `eval` + `parse` on returned `dput` string.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(
   ...
   r_text TEXT
   ...
)
```

```r
# PREPARED STATEMENT
sql <- "INSERT INTO my_table(r_text) VALUES (?r_obj)"

# BIND PARAMETER OF DPUT STRING OUTPUT
query <- DBI::sqlInterpolate(conn, sql, r_obj = capture.output(dput(mtcars)))

# EXECUTE ACTION
dbExecute(conn, query)

# RETRIEVE CONTENT
sql <- "SELECT r_text FROM my_table"
pg_data <- dbGetQuery(conn, sql)

# UNSERIALIZE RETURNED RAW VECTOR
mtcars_from_pg <- eval(parse(text=pg_data$r_text[1]))
```